# Google Spreadsheet > Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api

Editable Link - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vrzchTHVwwzc9wgFGmtc_zBsh27CEtE7KOyeNDuLwC0/edit?usp=sharing

Published to Web - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRaJd3YpKnemAneU47RI58m7cxQsYFdViFBxJPVCrb8ehbLMqIqU6yNhchJzdroflL8IhA5s6V56IJP/pubhtml

API Link - https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/2PACX-1vRaJd3YpKnemAneU47RI58m7cxQsYFdViFBxJPVCrb8ehbLMqIqU6yNhchJzdroflL8IhA5s6V56IJP/public/basic

When I structure my sheet API link it returned a *page not found* message. I am following the structure presented in the Developer Tools (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#retrieve_row_data) and yet the continues to show as unaccessible.

Is there a different struct I should follow or has google made changes to the accessibility of if the spreadsheet API?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#retrieve_row_data this is a migration guide and you are using their deprecated v3 API https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/2PACX-1vRaJd3YpKnemAneU47RI58m7cxQsYFdViFBxJPVCrb8ehbLMqIqU6yNhchJzdroflL8IhA5s6V56IJP/public/basic

the v3 API is shutdown https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/migrate-your-apps-use-latest-sheets-api

use v4 API instead (click V4 API tab in the guide)